# Не работает запрос через Retrofit

Tags: android, запрос, retrofit2

Такая проблема, ломаю голову целый день. в MainActivity срабатывает запрос через retrofit на получение фильмов , а в Detail.activity отдельный запрос на получение трейлеров к фильму не срабатывает. Не знаю куда копать уже.

По дебагин` вижу что запрос не срабатывает. Вот код с Gitaba

https://github.com/Serg8787/MoviesForResume

вот код который не срабатывает строка Response response) {
                TrailerApiResponse trailerApiResponse = response.body();

```
  public class DetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ResultMovie result;
    private ImageView imageViewPosterPath;
    private TextView textViewTitle;
    private TextView textViewRelis;
    private TextView textViewRating;
    private TextView textViewDescription;
    private String posterPath;
    private RecyclerView recyclerViewTrailer;
    private TrailerAdapter trailerAdapter;
    private ArrayList<ResultTrailer> trailerList;
    private TextView textViewTrailer;
    private Service trailerApiService;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);
        textViewTrailer = findViewById(R.id.textViewTrailer);


        textViewTitle = findViewById(R.id.textViewTitle);
        textViewDescription = findViewById(R.id.textViewDescription);
        textViewRating = findViewById(R.id.textViewRating);
        textViewRelis = findViewById(R.id.textViewRelis);
        imageViewPosterPath = findViewById(R.id.imageViewPosterPath);


        Intent intent = getIntent();
        if (intent != null && intent.hasExtra("data")) {
            result = intent.getParcelableExtra("data");

            posterPath = result.getPosterPath();
            String imagePath = "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/" + posterPath;
            Glide.with(this).load(imagePath).into(imageViewPosterPath);

            textViewTitle.setText(result.getOriginalTitle());
            textViewRelis.setText(result.getReleaseDate());
            textViewRating.setText(Double.toString(result.getVoteAverage()));
            textViewDescription.setText(result.getOverview());
//            getTrailer();
        }

   }
   private void getTrailer() {
        int movie_id = result.getId();
        Client Client = new Client();
        Service trailerApiService = Client.getClient().create(Service.class);
        Call<TrailerApiResponse> call = trailerApiService.getTrailer(movie_id,"0f18faa4acaadedc40202a9bf681eea1");
        call.enqueue(new Callback<TrailerApiResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<TrailerApiResponse> call, Response<TrailerApiResponse> response) {
                TrailerApiResponse trailerApiResponse = response.body();

                Toast.makeText(DetailActivity.this, ""+movie_id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<TrailerApiResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.i("error", t.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(DetailActivity.this, "No trailer", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: а в чем проблема сравнить с тем кодом который у вас в mainActivity?

Comment: код по запросу там одинаковый, в майнактивити добавлена только пагинация

Comment: а что вообще значит не срабатывает? У Вас ошибка какая-то в логах есть? или, может,  Вы onClickListener  не повесили?)

Comment: Ммм, я пробую через дебаггинг строчку  TrailerApiResponse trailerApiResponse = response.body(); и логе должен срабатывать запрос на трейлеры к фильмам..

Comment: немного не понял, что значит через дебаггинг?

Comment: Нужную строку помечаешь красным кружком, в месте где идет номер строки кода Потом нажимаешь жучка сверху. )))

Comment: @EnderFox Вы можете добавить текущий код DetailActivity полностью в вопрос? Потому что пока что понятно только то, что не вызывается коллбэк успешного обращения в сеть. Значит либо обращение неуспешно либо его нет. Текущего кода недостаточно,чтобы понять, возможно ли отсутствие обращения в принципе. Кроме того, Вы проверяли, вызывается ли `onFailure`?

Comment: @EnderFox нужен полный код самой DetailActivity, то, чем Вы дополнили вопрос, вряд ли связано с проблемой

Comment: @EnderFox `//            getTrailer();` а оно и при запуске закомментировано?)

Comment: Да. Я пробывал и раскоментить..Я думаю проблема где то в другом.

Comment: Это вызов функции, которая не вызывается, раскоментить точно надо. Если закоментите - не заработает никак.

Comment: Кроме того у Вас вызов происходит по условию `if (intent != null && intent.hasExtra("data"))` поставьте на ЭТОЙ строчке свой красный кружочек и проверьте, выполняется ли условие, если нет - то в этом и проблема)

Comment: Этот код срабатывает if (intent != null && intent.hasExtra("data")), на эмуляторе данные эти получаются. Detail активити - эти данные получает , а ниже через запрос, который не срабатывает, хочу загрузить в Recycler трейлеры фильма.

Comment: срабатывает он - это понятно. Но с каким результатом он срабатывает? чему равен intent? что возвращает intent.hasExtra("data")?

Comment: ММ..извини что замучал, только зарегился и пока без опыта))). Результат объект-фильм с майнактивити.  Для не работающего запроса мы с него берем только id, чтобы как раз к выбранному фильму с МайнАктивити, загрузить трейлеры

Comment: Да ничего)) Кстати, чтобы было более явно видно, что и как Вы проверяете - лучше при обращении на форумы использовать не дебаггер, а логирование. Например, написать перед условником такие две строки: `Log.e("TAG", intent.toString());` и `Log.e("TAG", intent.hasExtra("data");`

Comment: @EnderFox Вы меня неправильно поняли) Я имел ввиду не как ДОЛЖНО работать, а как работает сейчас, а конкретно "чему равен intent? что возвращает intent.hasExtra("data")?"

Comment: В моем случает надо сделать так        ?                                                                                            
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Log.i("TAG",intent.toString());
        if (intent != null && intent.hasExtra("data")) {

Comment: Да, только `Log.e("TAG", intent.hasExtra("data");` забыли) Это нужно вставить прямо перед `if...` затем запустить и открыть LogCat. В момент, когда должно быть обращение в сеть, Вы, как я думаю, увидите в LogCat две записи, одна -  про intent, вторая - вида "TAG false". Если так и будет, значит у Вас ошибка в работе с `putExtra`. Я на полтора часа ухожу от компа, как вернусь - постараюсь помочь) Удачи!

Comment: У меня ничего не выводится. Пусто. Не пойму, к чему как вяжется интент к проблеме. Мы можем вставить запрос в любом месте ведь и  я брал id фильма и вставлял в запрос числом,  а не брал с интента. На сайте https://developers.themoviedb.org/3/movies/get-movie-videos такой запрос срабатывает, а у меня нет...

Comment: @EnderFox можете залить текущий код на гит? я попробую найти ошибку, если хотите

Comment: https://github.com/Serg8787/Movies

Comment: @EnderFox у меня после раскомментирования `getTrailer();` всё заработало

Comment: Ммм, ну у меня как бы уже раскоментировано и нечего не работает. А как вы проверели, что все работает?

Comment: @EnderFox  у меня вывелся соответсвующий тостик, логи показали, что `onResponse` вызвался. Дебаггер остановился на строке `TrailerApiResponse trailerApiResponse = response.body();`

Comment: А кстати да. У меня также. Хорошо, спасибо. Завтра буду заливать в recycler. Попробую. 100$ вам в карму!

Comment: У тост тоже высвечивался. Я начал парится, что дебаггинг в майнактивит - запрос полностью показывает, а в детайл активити - нет.